# How sqlmap internally works?

Tags: sql-injection, wireshark, sqlmap

I'm trying to capture sqlmap traffic but I only see a single HTTP GET in wireshark without sql injection (its just the url I provide).

I would expect 1 HTTP GET request per try (per sql injection then).

How is sqlmap working to make its attemps ? How to see these attempts ?

Increase verbosity hasn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after hours !

Sqlmap is storing a cache I found in (windows)

```
C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local
```

After removing it, I was able to see the http queries.
Ouf !

(--refresh-queries has no effect)

Comment: I also want to investigate this tool to learn some basics about sql attack. Could your show me your steps on learning the internals of SqlMap?